# On place order button this error comes up "address" is required. Enter and try again. "address" is required. Enter and try again."

Tags: magento2, checkout, billing-address, address

"address" is required. Enter and try again. "address" is required. Enter and try again.
On place order button

Any idea ,what m missing ?

Comment: Check log error

Comment: Shows -rest/us/V1/carts/mine/billing-address 400 (Bad Request)

Comment: Restart the apche and mysql and check the your private window

Comment: Hello mohit , this comes up here -  {"message":"\"%fieldName\" is required. Enter and try again.","parameters":{"fieldName":"address"},

Comment: Are you trying to place an order by login into your customer account?
Make sure you have added all the required field to process with order. ???

Comment: yup with logged in customer , all fields have proper values in it.

Comment: you logout the customer account and after place order new user and check is that same error ..

Comment: Ok mohit , let me check